# Extract specific lines from multiple text files

Tags: java, python, perl, awk, sed

I want to print certain lines from multiple text files in a folder, depending on the file name. Consider the following text files named from 3 words separated by underscore:

```
Small_Apple_Red.txt
Small_Orange_Yellow.txt
Large_Apple_Green.txt
Large_Orange_Green.txt
```

How can the following be achieved?

```
if (first word of file name is "Small") {
   // Print row 3 column 2 of the file (space delimited);
}

if (second word of file name is "Orange") {
   // print row 1 column 4 of the file;
}
```

Is this possible with awk?

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow.

Use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) for to handle the files in a folder.

Then use regular expression for check the file name. Here
[grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) uses for extract the particular content from a file.

```
my $path = "folderpath";
while (my $file = glob("$path/*"))
{
    if($file =~/\/Small_Apple/)
    {
        open my $fh, "<", "$file";
        print grep{/content what you want/ } <$fh>;
    }

}
```

Comment: @amatek Yes. This is for perl

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file_names = ("Small_Apple_Red.txt",
                  "Small_Orange_Yellow.txt",
                  "Large_Apple_Green.txt",
                  "Large_Orange_Green.txt");

foreach my $file ( @file_names) {
    if ( $file =~ /^Small/){ // "^" marks the begining of the string
         print "\n $file has the first word small";
    }
    elsif ( $file =~ /.*?_Orange/){  // .*? is non-greedy, this means that it matches anything<br>
                                  //  until the first "_" is found
        print "\n $file has the second word orange";
    }
}
```

There is still a special case it your file has "Small_Orange" you have to decide which is more important. If the second word is more important, then switch the content from `if` section with the content from `elsif` section

Answer (score 0):

In Awk:

```
awk 'FILENAME ~ /^Large/ {print $1,$4}
     FILENAME ~ /^Small/ {print $3,$2}' *
```

in Perl:

```
perl -naE 'say "$F[0] $F[3]" if $ARGV =~ /^Large/;
           say "$F[2] $F[1]" if $ARGV =~ /^Small/ ' *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Basename;

my $dir = getcwd(); #or shift the input values from the user 
my @txtfiles = glob("$dir/*.txt");

foreach my $each_txt_file (@txtfiles)
{
    open(DATA, $each_txt_file) || die "reason: $!";
    my @allLines = <DATA>;
    (my $removeExt = $each_txt_file)=~s/\.txt$//g;
    my($word1, $word2, $word3) = split/\_/, basename $removeExt; #Select the file name with matching case
    if($word1=~m/small/i) #Select your match case
    {
        my @split_space = "";
        my @allrows = split /\n/, $allLines[1]; #Mentioned the row number
        my @allcolns = split /\s/, $allrows[0]; 
        print "\n", $allcolns[1]; #Mentioned the column number
    }
}
```